# Query 3 separate data sets or 1 joined set?

Tags: c#, sql, performance

This question can actually be applied to any language.
It is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306074/using-a-single-joined-query-instead-of-multiple-queries-for-performance), but not quite the same.

I have a website application that will be displaying data from database.
Three DB tables:

```
tblProfessor(Id,FirstName,LastName)
tblStudent(Id,FirstName,LastName)
tblProfessorStudent(Id,StudentId,ProfessorId)
```

So we have Students and Professors. Students can be taught by multiple professors and professors can teach multiple students.

Two ways of querying data:

1. return a join of all three tables, in which case we transfer some
   duplicate data.
2. return three sets for each of the table. I know
   multiple sets of data can be returned in one call from my web
   application. I'm not clear about mechanics of that call, but I think
   it will be just one connection to the DB (in contrast to the similar question mentioned above).

The query in the first case:

```
select
    ProfessoirId = p.Id
   ,ProfessorFirstName = p.FirstName
   ,ProfessorLastName = p.LastName
   ,StudentId = s.Id
   ,StudentFirstName = s.FirstName
   ,StudentLastName = s.LastName
from tblProfessorStudent ps
inner join tblProfessor p
   on p.id = ps.ProfessorId
inner join tblStudent s
   on s.id = ps.StudentId
```

The duplication that I am talking about is returning first and last names of student and professor per each row - combination of "Student is taught by professor" and "professor teaches students". The duplication results in extra amount of kb that needs to be transferred from DB to the app.

The query in the second case will be as simple as this:

```
select <columns> from tblProfessor
select <columns> from tblStudent
select <columns> from tblProfessorStudent
```

How should I approach querying data for my app **from the performance perspective**?

Answer (score 1):

From a pure performance perspective, there's nothing that beats the SQL Server's ability to join data sets in T-SQL. Especially when we are talking about large data sets.
Its sole purpose in life is to manage data and data sets, and it does that where the source of the data is.
Joining "over the wire"/on the client will introduce a great deal of (network) overhead, redundant data traffic, and there's no or close to no way that fancy client algorithms can overcome this.

Of course, and as usual: YMMV, "it depends" is always applicable to my statement.

Comment: I do not doubt ability of T-SQL to join data. I worry about duplicate data being sent from DB to my app.

Comment: I don't see the problem with duplicate data, can you elaborate?

Comment: I have edited my post with details regarding the query and the source of duplication

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about performance, then you should not return all rows from your tables. Once the database grows, this will cause the application to slow down. You should filter your data to get only the rows you need to display to the user. You can also consider implementing paging, so that you don't display a lot of rows at once.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what matters most in this case is how you are using the data. If you have the correct indexes implemented, SQL Server will join the tables just fine, don’t worry about it. I’m pretty sure it will be faster than running 3 selects. You said you are worried about duplicate data, but what sort of duplication? If you join the 3 tables you’ll have the real data, I mean, teachers that teach X students and students that are taught by X teachers. No duplications! So again, it depends on how you are using the result sets. Are you simply displaying a list of students and a list of teachers? In this case go with option 2. If you need to show Teacher A has the following students, then go with the join on option 1 because if you choose option 2, you will have to manipulate the ProfessorStudent data sets (which I  assume has only IDs) to get the names from the other 2 datasets and this is too much trouble in my opinion.

Comment: I have edited my post with details regarding the query and the source of duplication